# LFCN-490, which direction?

Tags: filter, radio, layout, 433mhz

From the data sheet of the LFCN-490 radio filter, the chip is marked with RF in, RF out and GND, but what is defined as RF in/out? I have seen some circuits using the rfm-22b with pin 1 (RF in) directed towards the antenna and RF out towards the circuitry, but I can't find how to be certain.

EDIT: Datasheet: https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/LFCN-490.pdf
Looking at the internal schematic, it looks like it's bidirectional, but then I don't see any reason for marking pin on and naming them in/out

Answer (score 1):

I expect that RF IN is where the signal goes in, and it comes out RF OUT.  In a receiver, the RF IN terminal should be closest to the antenna.

Comment: So you're saying it's the other way around in a transmitter? How about bidirectional, the receiver can also send data back to the transmitter but with your explanation it seems that this filter is not made for transceivers(?). I use it in an openlrsng module.

Comment: Since you did not provide links to the relevant datasheets, my answer is just a guess based on what you wrote in your question.

Comment: https://www.minicircuits.com/pdfs/LFCN-490.pdf

Comment: I would guess, based on the schematic on that datasheet, that the filter is symetrical, and either terminal can be used as input - but only Mini-Circuits would know for sure.

Comment: Yeh, I guess :\